# Bootstrap 4, can't align button to right

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4. I can't seem to right align the "Logout" button to the right:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ if eq .BaseURL "" }}/{{ else }}{{ .BaseURL }}{{ end }}">AppName</a>    
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link{{ if eq .Title "Home" }} active{{ else }}{{ end }}" href="{{ if eq .BaseURL "" }}/{{ else }}{{ .BaseURL }}{{ end }}">Push<span class="sr-only">{{ if eq .Title "Home" }}(current){{ end }}</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link{{ if eq .Title "SomeFunction" }} active{{ else }}{{ end }}" href="{{ .BaseURL }}/somefunction">SomeFunction<span class="sr-only">{{ if eq .Title "Inflight" }}(current){{ end }}</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="navbar-item pull-right">
          <a class="nav-link{{ if eq .Title "Logout" }} active{{ else }}{{ end }}" href="{{ .BaseURL }}/logout">LogoutX<span class="sr-only"></span>{{ if eq .Title "Logoff" }}(current){{ end }}</span></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mr-auto` for `ul` and add `logout` option as sibling

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ if eq .BaseURL "" }}/{{ else }}{{ .BaseURL }}{{ end }}">AppName</a>    
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link{{ if eq .Title "Home" }} active{{ else }}{{ end }}" href="{{ if eq .BaseURL "" }}/{{ else }}{{ .BaseURL }}{{ end }}">Push<span class="sr-only">{{ if eq .Title "Home" }}(current){{ end }}</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link{{ if eq .Title "SomeFunction" }} active{{ else }}{{ end }}" href="{{ .BaseURL }}/somefunction">SomeFunction<span class="sr-only">{{ if eq .Title "Inflight" }}(current){{ end }}</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <li class="navbar-item">
        <a class="nav-link{{ if eq .Title "Logout" }} active{{ else }}{{ end }}" href="{{ .BaseURL }}/logout">LogoutX<span class="sr-only"></span>{{ if eq .Title "Logoff" }}(current){{ end }}</span></a>
    </li>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**HTML Version**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">AppName</a>    
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Push<span class="sr-only">Home</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">SomeFunction<span class="sr-only">Inflight</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <li class="navbar-nav navbar-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">LogoutX<span class="sr-only">Logoff</span></a>
    </li>   
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not working for me. It looks exactly the same. I even added the `ul` tags. Did I miss something?

Comment: i added mr-auto in ul and also  remove li logout from ul and make it separate

Comment: Wondering... Doesn't using `li` need `ul` or `ol` encapsulation tags to be valid HTML?

Comment: yep, you can. did you find your solution ?